# What is the PHP equivalent of this cookie code in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I want to check the same condition as the given code which is in JavaScript using jQuery.

```
if ($.cookie('nwsubl') == 1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can do as follow:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['nwsubl']) && $_COOKIE['nwsubl'] == 1){
    // Do something
}
```

`isSet()` is used to check whether variable exist or not. `==` loosely compares the values.

You can set cookie using `setcookie()` See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: if it is not equal to 1 then how can we write this

Comment: if(isset($_COOKIE['nwsubl']) && $_COOKIE['nwsubl'] != 1){
}